# Error when importing existing URL into Jasonette in android studio

Tags: android, mobile, web-applications, jasonette

I am new to jasonette and android studio for that matter. I have an existing web app mysite.com for sake of argument. I am following the tutorial here - https://docs.jasonette.com/android/. Under step 6 it says I can import my url and app name which I have done. I get a blank screen at that url but was under the impression if I had a complete web app already built using php. Anyone know how I can achieve this? All I am looking to do is have my current web app open in a android app and possibly having it in the app store. I have seen this done for ios but not android. Thanks!

Here is the strings.xml file -

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">My Site</string>
<string name="url">mysite.com</string>
<string name="launch">file:mysite.com</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the URL you enter against the property `url` actually points to a valid JSON document. That's how it works.

From the same documentation,

`A. Update JSON URL
Update the url property inside strings.xml to your own JSON url. That's it! Build and run the app and you'll find that it's turned into your own app!`

So ensure the URL that you are using is pointing to a valid JSON with proper Jasonette structure. If you do not have a JSON handy you can use [one of these existing JSONs](http://docs.jasonette.com/examples/) that are provided with the tutorial.

In case your URL is already pointing to a JSON doc and still it is not showing in the app, pasting the JSON (or pointing towards it) would help to debug.

Comment: Thank you, I did not create a json file to point to.. This was very simple and works great!